# Inline svg scaling - auto width

Tags: css, html, svg, responsive-design, scale

I've built a responsive dashboard, and a new requirement is big-screen tv viewing. To accomplish scaling of logo assets, I've decided to use SVGs, which also remove the need to maintain a seperate retina sprite for mobile/desktop viewing.

As the logos are all different widths, I need to set a common height, with the width being auto. This works great when using svgs with an img tag, but when using inline SVGs the paths scale nicely, but the svg width is still set to the viewBox sizing.

If need be I can settle for the img option, but would really prefer to use the inline option, so I can control the colours of the paths with css.

I've setup a jsfiddle to show an example. the red keyline shows the sizing issue on the two elements.
http://jsfiddle.net/bxeBW/2/

```
<svg version="1.1" id="DT" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="445.997px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 445.997 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">

.logo{
    height:3em;
    padding: 0.5em;

    svg, 
    img{
      height:3em;
      width:auto;
      border: 1px solid #ff0000;

        #telegraph{
            fill:#ff0000;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: try and add the <code>display: flex;</code> property to the logo class. A fiddle would help

Comment: thanks @fauverism. Unfortunately that didn't work. There is a fiddle link in the post body above.

Answer (score 1):

It appears, by adding max-width to the css for the svg, will format the sizing exactly as i need it. This works for Webkit browsers and Firefox, which fortunately meets my requirements, however if IE support was essential then this is not really a solution.

```
.logo{
    svg, 
    img{
      height:3em;
      max-width:100%;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bxeBW/3/